# How to Delete Specific Node in Firebase Android from ListView

Tags: android, firebase, listview, crud, onitemclicklistener

I got a prpblem. I want to delete selected ListView and specific nodes which refer to key numbers (20191, 20192,...as highlighted) and their children.
[here's my Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPibl.png)

here is my OnItemClickListener with focus on case 2 to delete ListView

```js
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                final Aduanclass aduanclass = aduanclassList.get(position);
//                selectedPosition = position;
//                itemSelected = true;
//                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
//                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_common_detail_aduan);
//                                dialog.setTitle("Pilih Aksi");
//                dialog.show();
//                final String Selection=arrayList.get(position);

                final CharSequence [] dialog ={"Lihat Detail", "Ubah", "Hapus"};
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Pilihan");

                builder.setItems(dialog, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        switch (which){
                            case 0:
                                Intent intentCommondetail= new Intent(MainActivity.this,CommonDetailAduan.class);
                                intentCommondetail.putExtra("primekeyy", aduanclass.getPrimekey());
                                intentCommondetail.putExtra("kategory", aduanclass.getKategori());
                                intentCommondetail.putExtra("deskripsy",aduanclass.getDeskripsi());
//                                intentCommondetail.putExtra("kategori",Selection);
//                                intentCommondetail.putExtra("deskripsi",Selection);
                                startActivity(intentCommondetail);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                Intent intentCommonedit= new Intent(MainActivity.this,CommonUpdateAduan.class);
//                                intentCommonedit.putExtra("primekeyy", aduanclass.getPrimekey());
                                intentCommonedit.putExtra("primekeyy", aduanclass.getPrimekey());
                                intentCommonedit.putExtra("kategory", aduanclass.getKategori());
                                intentCommonedit.putExtra("deskripsy",aduanclass.getDeskripsi());
//                                intentCommondetail.putExtra("kategori",Selection);
//                                intentCommondetail.putExtra("deskripsi",Selection);
                                startActivity(intentCommonedit);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                deleteData(primkey);
                        }
                    }
                });
                builder.create().show();
            }
        });
        ((ArrayAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and here is my deleteData method

```js
private void deleteData(final String primkey) {
        DatabaseReference mDatabase1 =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("aduan").getRef();
        mDatabase1.removeValue();
```

I tried to run the code but instead of deleting specific listView and specific node in Firebase Database, it deleted all the children of "aduan"

FYI, i set the key numbers to be automatically increased by +1 on each addition in data input but I don't know how to refer to the key numbers.

Thanks for yor help

Comment: You have never used primary key in the database reference

Answer (score 0):

You have never used primkey in the database reference. Code should be like this

```java
private void deleteData(final String primkey) {
        DatabaseReference mDatabase1 =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("aduan").child(primkey);
        mDatabase1.removeValue();
}
```

Comment: i've tried this but still failed. How to refer child(primkey) to child of "aduan" ?

I tried this code to declare String but it also couldn't help
primkey = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("aduan").getKey();

Comment: @developerbdkmedan can you give example for childs in "aduan"

Comment: of course, here is my database structure, you can click the link to view

[My Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPibl.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void deleteData(final String primkey) {
    DatabaseReference mDatabase1 =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("aduan").getRef();
    mDatabase1.removeValue();
```

The above is getting a reference your database ref with the parent node being returned for aduan.you are supposed to navigate inside the aduan node by using

```
private void deleteData(final String primkey) {
    DatabaseReference mDatabase1 =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("aduan").child("replace with child node key here");
    mDatabase1.removeValue();
```

Once you have done that you have to notify the listViewAdapter of the changes made so that it can refresh the content.
I hope this helps.

Comment: the node key is set to be automatically getting auto incremented number (first input will get 20191, second input will get 20192, and so on). it's not set manually so i can't put the child name inside child()